# What thresholding (binarization) algorithm is used in Tesseract OCR?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, adaptive-threshold

I am working on a project that needs accurate OCR results for images with rich background. So I am comparing results of two OCRs (one of them is Tesseract) to make my choice. The point is that results are strongly affected by the pre-processing step and especially image binarization. I extracted the binarized image of the other OCR and passed it to Tesseract which enhanced the results of Tesseract by 30-40%.

I have two questions and your answers would be of much help to me:

1. What binarization algorithm does tesseract use, and is it configurable?
2. Is there a way to extract the binarized image of Tesseract OCR so I can test the other OCR with it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I have found the answers to my questions:

1- The binarization algorithm used is Otsu thresholding. You can see it [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/ccmain/thresholder.cpp) in line 179.

2- To get the binarized image, a method in tesseract api can be called:

```
PIX* thresholded = api->GetThresholdedImage(); //thresholded must be freed
```

Comment: Above link is broken, [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/src/ccmain/thresholder.cpp#L210) is a hopefully more permanent one. (BTW edit queue for this answer seems be full if someone can fix that)

Answer (score 6):

Otsu thresholding is a global filter. You can use some local filter to get better results.
You can look for Sauvalo's binarization see [here](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/mvg/files/pdf/pdf_24.pdf)or Nick's [here](http://www.math-info.univ-paris5.fr/~vincent/articles/DRR_nick_binarization_09.pdf) . Those both algorithm are Niblack's improvement.
I used it to binarize my image for an OCR and I get better result
Good luck